# Where to securely store Web API credentials in iPhone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, security

My iPhone app connects to an API that requires credentials to use it. Where can i securely store these credentials? I have them set up as a constants in the implementation file of the class that handles communicating with the API, but I've got a feeling that this may be a security issue and someone may be able to access this.

Thanks

Comment: In the Keychain? Perhaps a read of Apple's developer documentation is in order.

Comment: Yeah I though about the keychain... But then how do I get them into the keychain on the first run without declaring them somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Keychain is appropriate for dynamic credentials (user login/password)

Static credentials such as API/AppKey credentials are inherently insecure, since no matter how you put them in the application, a determined individual can get to them.  The "norm" is to just drop them into the app as #defines and go from there.  Alternatively I suppose you could have them as encrypted defines and decrypt them as needed.  All told, probably not worth the effort in most cases.